# Unable to get property 'aDataSort' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

i trying to have search option to table .. here is the code

```
$('#dtreport').dataTable({
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sLengthMenu": 'Display <select name="dtAgents_length" aria-controls="dtAgents" class="form-control input-sm">' +
                                                    '<option value="5">5</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="10">10</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="25">25</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="50">50</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="75">75</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="100">100</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
                                                '</select> records',
                        "sInfo": '<label>Displaying _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records.</label>',
                        "sZeroRecords": '<center><span style="color: red;"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i>  No report found.</span></center>',
                        "sInfoEmpty": '<label>Displaying 0 to 0 of 0 records.</label>',
                        "sInfoFiltered": '<label>(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)</label>'
                    },
                    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 'All']],
                    "iDisplayLength": 5
                });
```

i am getting a different run-time errors like

if table is empty

> Unhandled exception at line 65, column 340 in jquery.dataTables.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'aDataSort' of undefined or null reference

if table has data

> Unhandled exception at line 85, column 496 in jquery.dataTables.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference

please help with this issue...
 thank you....